# Complex valued function satisfying CREs yet not differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I cannot work a famous example used to show that a function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations at a point (origin) but is not differentiable at that point:

$f(z)=\dfrac{z^5}{\mid z^4 \mid}$ when $z \ne 0$, $f=0$ when $z=0$.

There are two steps I am unsure how to go about.

1. Show $f$ is not differentiable at origin.
2. Verify CREs by calculating partial derivatives by definition.

Expanding $f$ using $z=x+iy$, we get

$f = \dfrac{x^5-10x^3y^5+5xy^4}{x^8+4x^6y^2+6x^4y^4+4x^2y^6+y^8} + i \times\dfrac{5x^4y-10x^2y^3+y^5}{x^8+4x^6y^2+6x^4y^4+4x^2y^6+y^8}$

$f = u(x,y) +i v (x,y)$

Calculating $\partial u/\partial x$ by definition at origin will apparently lead to $\infty$ i.e. limit does not exist.

How does one go about it?

Comment: If it satisfies the CREs but isn't differentiable, then it is not differentiable as a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, ie it is not Frechet differentiable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative There are a million different ways to show that a function is not Frechet/total differentiable, but one sufficient way would to be show (if possible) that its directional derivatives in different directions are different. Have you tried that already? The easiest case is when you can show that the partial derivatives are different (since they are directional derivatives)

Comment: To show that $f$ is not differentiable at the origin, you just find several paths such that the limits do not agree.

To verify Cauchy-Riemann equations, I think it would be better to start from the definitions of partial derivatives, i.e. you write $\frac{f(a+0i)-f(0)}{a}$ and $\frac{f(0+bi)-f(0)}{bi}$ and then take limits as $a$ and $b$ approaches $0$.

Comment: I tried $y=0$ and $x\to 0$ (similar to calculating partial wrt x). But I had trouble evaluating the limit.

Comment: You do not need to find the real part ($u$) and imaginary part ($v$) of $f$. You can simply prove $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, and this equality is equivalent to Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Missed a radical sign in the denominator, if you have that its easy. Case closed

Comment: If it's not differentiable at a point, how come you say it satisfies the CR equations at that point?

Comment: @NgChungTak CREs by themselves are necessary not sufficient conditions for differentiability..